# windows server returns 404 when tried to request POST using Alamofire (swift)

Tags: ios, swift, http, windows-server-2019

I am trying to post a json object to my windows server but it returns 404 each time. I'm using the Alamofire library since it's really convenient to use. The server returns 200 (ok) when i try to use the get method and when i send my post request to "https://httpbin.org/post" to test my code. I'm guessing there is something wrong with the server side but i can't figure out what.

Here is my client side code, in case something is wrong with it:

```
let urlSend = "http://171.217.5.232:1015/post"
let params = [
    "Action": "sendCode",
    "Email": enteredEmail,
    "Code": code
]

AF.request(urlSend, method: .post, parameters: params, encoder: JSONParameterEncoder.default).responseJSON { response in
    debugPrint(response)
}
```

Comment: You may first check if the URL is correct. When `https://httpbin.org/` is your base URL, is "post" actually your endpoint where you send a POST request? In this special case, 404 _likely_ means, the server didn't found your "post" endpoint. In addition, you may utilise tools to check basic endpoint functionality with cURL, etc.. or more sophisticated tools which act as "man in the middle" and observe your traffic from your device to the server (Charles Proxy, etc.).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **Alamofire.upload** and this is going to work

```
    Alamofire.upload(multipartFormData: { (MultipartFormData) in
        for (key, value) in params {
            if let data = value.data(using: .utf8) {
                MultipartFormData.append(data, withName: key)
            }
        }
    }, usingThreshold: UInt64.init(), to: url, method: .post, headers: header) { (results) in
        
    }
```

Comment: Do i upload the json object as a document or to a document?

Comment: You can use JSONSerialization and make json with Dictionary of json objects  and convert it to String and upload the string